# Playing sound in background in python while GUI is running with tkinter

Tags: python, pygame, python-playsound

I have been trying to run sound in background while App is running. I am Arch Linux and Python 3.8
I have tried playsound as like this

```
playsound('music.mp3', False)
```

but I get error saying system not supported. I have also tried pygame following way:

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("music.mp3")
mixer.music.play()
```

But I get error `pygame.error: Unrecognized audio format`. Is there any other way I can run music in background some task is executing on GUI with tkinter. The program will run on arch and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code it will run the background music continuously till the app is running

```
mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Comment: I still get error `pygame.error: Unrecognized audio format`. I don't want it to run continuously either. Its gonna play for 10s only

Comment: convert your mp3 file to .wav format then it will 100% work

Comment: Thanks using wav format worked. Can you also tell me if there is a way in mixer to kill process after 10s

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mixer.music.play(-1)
```

And if you want your background music to be stopped in 10s then add this too:

```
gui_name.after(10000,  mixer.music.stop)
```

Hope it will help you.